# How to install tar ball sublime text on Ubuntu?

Tags: sublime-text

I recently installed sublime text 3 from tarball via https://www.sublimetext.com/3.

What I get is

- changelog.txt
- Icon
- plugin_host
- python3.3.zip
- sublime.py
- sublime_text.desktop
- crash_reporter
- Packages
- sublime_plugin.py
- sublime_text

When I run ./sublime_text, yes, the application launches.
However, it does not say sublime text was installed.
It is only accessible from the commandline.
How can I access to the sublimetext from desktop or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tarball is not meant to install sublime text on the system.

Instead use a package from the apt repository:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

# stable version
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Source: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you very much. By the way, why do you think the tarball is provided?

Comment: If you are not the admin user of a machine, then you can run sublime from your home without installing it system wide.

Comment: Interesting! Since I have been working on my own PC, there was no such perspective. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mv ./sublime_text_3/ /opt/sublime_text/
sudo cp /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

That's it! Now you can search for the sublime in system applications and execute it.